Why am I recieving these errors?
When I run my code(available at https://github.com/ayaangrover/waffle) I recieve these errors:
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseAuth

// …

struct ContentView: View {

    // …

    private func signInWithGoogle() {
// Line 40:
        guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else {
            print("Failed to get client ID")
            return
        }
        
        let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
        
// Line 47:
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: getRootViewController()) { user, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error during sign-in: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let authentication = user?.authentication,
                  let idToken = authentication.idToken,
                  let accessToken = authentication.accessToken else {
                print("Error retrieving tokens")
                return
            }
            
            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)
            
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error signing in with Google: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    // Successfully signed in
                    self.user = authResult?.user
                    self.isSignedIn = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // …

}



/Users/ayaangrover/Documents/Github/waffle/Waffle/Waffle/ContentView.swift:40:30 Cannot find 'FirebaseApp' in scope
/Users/ayaangrover/Documents/Github/waffle/Waffle/Waffle/ContentView.swift:47:67 Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to expected argument type 'String?'
/Users/ayaangrover/Documents/Github/waffle/Waffle/Waffle/ContentView.swift:47:92 Extra trailing closure passed in call

Also, I have Firebase and GoogleSignIn installed in Package Dependencies.

On Stack Overflow, do not require the reader to use links to external information. Everything should be in the question itself so future readers always have immediate access to it. If you have code, copy and paste it into the question so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Error 1:

ContentView.swift:40 :: Cannot find 'FirebaseApp' in scope

guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else {

FirebaseApp is defined in the FirebaseCore Framework, which your code does not import.
Add import FirebaseCore.
...and if that doesn't work, there's plenty of other things to check.

Error 2:

ContentView.swift:47 :: Cannot convert value of type UIViewController to expected argument type String?

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: getRootViewController()) { user, error in

Your code is calling the GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: presentingViewController) method, which was apparently removed a couple of years ago.
See the accepted answer from @Abdullah where he demonstrates how to call the replacement method.

Error 3:

ContentView.swift:47 :: Extra trailing closure passed in call

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: getRootViewController()) { user, error in

Same as above: your Swift code assumes there's a method parameter for a callback block in that position, when in-fact, there is not.

How do I fix error 3? What do I change

@AyaanGrover Fix error 2 first, and error 3 will be fixed with it.

To fix error 2, I removed with: config. Did I need to remove something else? Error 3 remains but two is gone

When I replace it all with (withPresenting: getRootViewController()), I get this error: /Users/ayaangrover/Documents/Github/waffle/Waffle/Waffle/ContentView.swift:45:46 Value of type 'GIDSignInResult' has no member 'authentication'
